# Field.getLong() returning incorrect value for various ranges of values (on Android)

Tags: java, android, reflection, long-integer, primitive-types

I'm using reflection to access some public static final long fields. Unfortunately the long returned by Field.getLong() is often not the same as the actual field value. Here is some code to demonstrate this (note - the values I've used *seem* to be where there is a boundary between ranges of correct and incorrect values, though there may be more boundaries):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test {
    public static final long HEX_00000000ffffffff = 0x00000000ffffffffL; // boundary case (up to here everything is fine)

    public static final long HEX_0000000100000000 = 0x0000000100000000L; // boundary case (from here goes pear-shaped)
    public static final long HEX_0000007fffffffff = 0x0000007fffffffffL; // boundary case (after this it stops being pear-shaped)
    public static final long HEX_0000008000000000 = 0x0000008000000000L; // boundary case (okay from here, for now)
    public static final long HEX_000000ffffffffff = 0x000000ffffffffffL; // boundary case (after this goes pear-shaped)

    public static final long HEX_0000010000000000 = 0x0000010000000000L; // boundary case (from here goes pear-shaped)
    public static final long HEX_00007fffffffffff = 0x00007fffffffffffL; // boundary case (after this it stops being pear-shaped)
    public static final long HEX_0000800000000000 = 0x0000800000000000L; // boundary case (okay from here, for now)
    public static final long HEX_0000ffffffffffff = 0x0000ffffffffffffL; // boundary case (after this goes pear-shaped)

    public static final long HEX_0001000000000000 = 0x0001000000000000L; // boundary case (from here goes pear-shaped)
    public static final long HEX_007fffffffffffff = 0x007fffffffffffffL; // boundary case (after this it stops being pear-shaped)
    public static final long HEX_0080000000000000 = 0x0080000000000000L; // boundary case (okay from here, for now)
    public static final long HEX_00ffffffffffffff = 0x00ffffffffffffffL; // boundary case (after this goes pear-shaped)

    public static final long HEX_0100000000000000 = 0x0100000000000000L; // boundary case (from here goes pear-shaped)
    public static final long HEX_ffffffff7fffffff = 0xffffffff7fffffffL; // boundary case (after this it stops being pear-shaped)
    public static final long HEX_ffffffff80000000 = 0xffffffff80000000L; // boundary case (from here everything is fine)

    public static void check() {
        try {
            for (Field fld : Test.class.getFields()) {
                String hex = Long.toHexString(fld.getLong(null));
                String expectedHex = fld.getName().replaceAll("^HEX_0*", "");
                boolean correct = hex.equals(expectedHex);
                Log.d("test", fld.getName() + "=" + "0x" + hex + " (" + (correct ? "correct" : "incorrect") + ")");
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("test", "failed", t);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
D/test: HEX_00000000ffffffff=0xffffffff (correct)
D/test: HEX_0000000100000000=0x1 (incorrect)
D/test: HEX_0000007fffffffff=0xffffffff (incorrect)
D/test: HEX_0000008000000000=0x8000000000 (correct)
D/test: HEX_000000ffffffffff=0xffffffffff (correct)
D/test: HEX_0000010000000000=0x100 (incorrect)
D/test: HEX_00007fffffffffff=0xffffffffff (incorrect)
D/test: HEX_0000800000000000=0x800000000000 (correct)
D/test: HEX_0000ffffffffffff=0xffffffffffff (correct)
D/test: HEX_0001000000000000=0x10000 (incorrect)
D/test: HEX_007fffffffffffff=0xffffffffffff (incorrect)
D/test: HEX_0080000000000000=0x80000000000000 (correct)
D/test: HEX_00ffffffffffffff=0xffffffffffffff (correct)
D/test: HEX_0100000000000000=0x1000000 (incorrect)
D/test: HEX_ffffffff7fffffff=0xffffffffffffffff (incorrect)
D/test: HEX_ffffffff80000000=0xffffffff80000000 (correct)
```

Tested on a Nexus 6P running the latest stock Android 8.0.

UPDATE: Reading the value using (Long)fld.get(null) has the same problem

UPDATE: Using Long instead of long, does NOT have the same problem

UPDATE: I reported the bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65267092).

Comment: You forgot to mention that on J2SE 8 your code runs fine and everything is "correct".

Comment: The fields in your output don't match your source code.  You have 16 in your source but 19 in output.

Comment: @Robert do you have a reference for the J2SE 8 claim?  Or a workaround for when running on Android?

Comment: @Mark Carter: Just try the code yourself as I did, it works.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey thanks, fixed

Comment: @Robert ok, thanks. But it doesn't work on a Nexus 6P running Android 8.0 and this is the problem

Comment: If something Java related (that does not use Android or Java7/8/9 specific code) works on Oracle J2SE (taking it as the reference) and not an Android it is clearly an Android bug.

Comment: How about Oracle J2SE 7?

Comment: You should better test it on Android 7 or 6, because Android 8 bases on OpenJDK whereas the versions before base on Apache Harmony. May be some Linux user can test it on OpenJDK, too.

Comment: Same problem on Android 6.

Comment: Fascinating! Have you demonstrated somewhere else that the bug is indeed in `Field#getLong()` and not `Long.toHexString()`? Also, what's the use case for reflecting something that's already `public static final`?

Comment: Confirmed, not a problem with Long.toHexString() :) . Use case is accessing from a dependency (common module).